# How to convert a string to function in Pyspark ( Dynamic function)

Tags: pyspark

I'm reading the json file in Pyspark and generate the function dynamically.

The below static function has been created before calling json file(dynamic function ).

```
def rh_concatenate(*arg):
    return concat(*arg)

def rh_date_to_char(column_name, format1):
    if (format1 == 'MM'):
        return lpad(month(column_name).cast(StringType()), 2, '0')
    elif (format1 == 'YYYY'):
        return lpad(year(column_name).cast(StringType()), 4, '0')
```

JSON file(Rule engine) will return the dictionary "exp_list".

exp_list dictionary contains key is 'QUARTER' and value is 'rh_concatenate ('Q3','-',rh_date_to_char ('TRANSACTION_DATE','YYYY' ) )'

Scenario 1:  It's not working

```
for key, value in exp_list.items():
    tran_df.withColumn(key, value).show()
```

Scenario 2: Working fine.

```
tran_df.withColumn('QUARTER', rh_concatenate ('Q3','-',rh_date_to_char ('TRANSACTION_DATE','YYYY' ) )).show()
```

I have tried multiple ways for executing scenario 1 and getting the below error.

```
AssertionError: col should be Column
```

Comment: Please show us at least 2 or 3 entries of `exp_list`.

Comment: Hi  cronoik, Please find the below entries of exp_list. item key : TRANSACTION_ID
item value:  rh_assign (('TRANSACTION_ID') )
item key : CREDIT_CARD_ID
item value:  rh_assign (('CREDIT_CARD_ID') )
item key : TRANSACTION_VALUE
item value:  rh_assign (('TRANSACTION_VALUE') )
item key : QUARTER
item value:  rh_concatenate ('Q3','-',rh_date_to_char ('TRANSACTION_DATE','YYYY' ) )
item key : TRANSACTION_SEGMENT
item value:  rh_assign (('TRANSACTION_SEGMENT') )
item key : TRANSACTION_DATE
item value:  rh_assign (('TRANSACTION_DATE') )

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine..

I have added eval() function and it's working fine.

```
tran_df.withColumn(key, eval(value)).show()
```

If value contain only one function, then you should add col() function,

```
tran_df.withColumn(key, col(value)).show()
```

Example,

```
def rh_assign(arg):
    return arg

tran_df.withColumn('TRANSACTION_ID', col(rh_assign (('TRANSACTION_ID') ))).show()
```

Comment: Please mark it as an answer when your question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

My dynamic function is too big and added eval function and it's working perfectly.

See the below my key & value.

```
item key : QUARTER
item value:  rh_if ((rh_less_than ((rh_str_to_num ((rh_date_to_char (('TRANSACTION_DATE'),('MM') )) )),('04') )),(rh_concatenate ((lit('Q1')),(lit('-')),(rh_date_to_char (('TRANSACTION_DATE'),('YYYY') )) )),(rh_if ((rh_less_than ((rh_str_to_num ((rh_date_to_char (('TRANSACTION_DATE'),('MM') )) )),(7) )),(rh_concatenate ((lit('Q2')),(lit('-')),(rh_date_to_char (('TRANSACTION_DATE'),('YYYY') )) )),(rh_if ((rh_less_than ((rh_str_to_num ((rh_date_to_char (('TRANSACTION_DATE'),('MM') )) )),(10) )),(rh_concatenate ((lit('Q3')),(lit('-')),(rh_date_to_char (('TRANSACTION_DATE'),('YYYY') )) )),(rh_concatenate ((lit('Q4')),(lit('-')),(rh_date_to_char (('TRANSACTION_DATE'),('YYYY') )) )) )) )) )
```

my code will be look like below,

```
for key, value in exp_list.items():
    print("item key :",key)
    print('item value: ', value)
    if key=='QUARTER':
        tran_df.withColumn(key, eval(value)).show()
```